# Dijkstra's and Prim's algorithms: correctness/efficiency

Tags: c++, graph, contest-problem, c++03

This is in preparation for a competition that only allows C++03.

```
// Neighbor index plus weight of edge connecting this vertex with neighbor
struct NeighborWeight
{
    Index neighbor;
    Distance weight;
};
// Represents adjacency information for a single vertex (contains all
// neighbors and weights of edges connecting them)
typedef std::list<NeighborWeight> AdjVertex;
// Represents adjacency information for all vertices (thus representing
// a complete directed/undirected graph)
typedef std::vector<AdjVertex> AdjList;

// Dijkstra's algorithm: computes SHORTEST PATH to all vertices from a starting
// vertex for a DIRECTED/UNDIRECTED graph with NONNEGATIVE edge weights.
// result.dist[v] = shortest distance from source to v.
// result.prev[v] = predecessor of v in shortest path from source to v.
// If v is not connected to start_vertex, dist[v] = max value of Distance, and
// prev[v] = -1.
// If v = start_vertex, prev[v] = -1.

// Prim's algorithm (call with do_prim = true): computes MINIMUM SPANNING TREE
// starting from a seed vertex for an UNDIRECTED graph with ANY edge weights.
// result.dist[v] should be ignored.
// result.prev[v] = parent of v in minimal spanning tree.
// If v is not connected to start_vertex, prev[v] = -1.
// If v = start_vertex, prev[v] = -1;

struct DijkstraResult
{
    std::vector<Distance> dist;
    std::vector<Index> prev;
};

DijkstraResult dijkstra(AdjList al, Index start_vertex, bool do_prim = false)
{
    typedef std::pair<Distance, Index> DistAndIndex;

    const Distance infinity = std::numeric_limits<Distance>::max();
    const Index undefined_index = -1;
    const Index num_vertices = al.size();

    std::vector<Distance> dist(num_vertices, infinity); // tentative distances
    std::vector<Index> prev(num_vertices, undefined_index); // predecessors
    std::vector<uint8_t> is_visited(num_vertices, false);
    std::set<DistAndIndex> unvisited_queue;

    dist[start_vertex] = 0;

    // Populate unvisited_queue in order with (Distance, Index) pairs
    unvisited_queue.insert(std::make_pair(0, start_vertex));
    for (Index v = 0; v < num_vertices; ++v)
        if (v != start_vertex)
            unvisited_queue.insert(unvisited_queue.end(),
            std::make_pair(infinity, v));

    while (!unvisited_queue.empty())
    {
        // u = index of unvisited vertex with least distance
        Index u = unvisited_queue.begin()->second;
        // If this least distance is infinity, break (no more connected verts)
        if (unvisited_queue.begin()->first == infinity) break;
        // Visit this vertex
        unvisited_queue.erase(unvisited_queue.begin());
        is_visited[u] = true;
        // In Prim's, distances are computed from the MST. Adding a vertex
        // to the MST makes the distance 0.
        if (do_prim) dist[u] = 0;
        // vert = vertex corresponding to u
        AdjVertex &vert = al[u];
        // Iterate through neighbors of u
        for (AdjVertex::iterator it = vert.begin(); it != vert.end(); ++it)
        {
            // v = it->neighbor is the index of the neighbor; it->weight is the
            // edge weight between u and v
            Index v = it->neighbor;
            // Skip if v is visited
            if (is_visited[v]) continue;
            // Now compute new dist for v
            Distance alt = dist[u] + it->weight;
            // And compare with previous
            if (alt < dist[v])
            {
                unvisited_queue.erase(std::make_pair(dist[v], v));
                unvisited_queue.insert(std::make_pair(alt, v));
                dist[v] = alt;
                prev[v] = u;
            }
        }
    }

    DijkstraResult res = { dist, prev };
    return res;
}
```

There's another set of `typedef`s and functions that duplicates a list of undirected edges into an `AdjList` structure.

Comment: *competition that only allows C++03* you should have entered this before 2011. By now the language standard has moved on.

Answer (score 2):

I'll address some minor things (unrelated to efficiency, at least):

- The comments describing the *algorithm* could be at the very top so that the code in between isn't missed.  Any comments describing the *functions* or the `typedef`s can stay above them.
- These `struct`s are in global scope, so they should be contained by something (such as a function) to put them into local scope, preventing unknown modifications.

  For instance, `DijkstraResult` could probably be defined in the calling code, which I assume is `main()` (not shown here).  Wherever the result of `dijkstra()` is received, that `struct` should be contained there.  This will also help with keeping code lower in scope, which eases maintenance and prevents bugs associated with this.
- If you still want a `typedef` for the `std::pair`, at least consider a less-obvious (and possibly more accurate) name.  The name `DistAndIndex` can still be read from the `std::pair`, so it doesn't help much.  It also doesn't save very many keystrokes, if that's even a concern.
- The name `infinity` doesn't make sense here as you're not assigning it to anything considered infinite (it's also not a number, but a concept).  It is assigned to a *max* value, which is *finite*, also according to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max).

  Bearing that in mind, a more appropriate name may be something like `maxDistance`.
- Curly braces should be used here:

  ```
  for (Index v = 0; v < num_vertices; ++v)
      if (v != start_vertex)
          unvisited_queue.insert(unvisited_queue.end(),
          std::make_pair(infinity, v));
  ```

  From a readability standpoint, it's not entirely clear what is contained in what.  It can also hurt maintainability as adding or removing code from here can break something.

  Regarding the code within the `if` block, the second line should be indented so that it is not read as a separate statement.

  ```
  for (Index v = 0; v < num_vertices; ++v)
  {
      if (v != start_vertex)
      {
          unvisited_queue.insert(unvisited_queue.end(),
              std::make_pair(infinity, v));
      }
  }
  ```
- `uint8_t` should be `std::uint8_t` in C++.